# Django SUM Query with VIEW Statement

Tags: python, django

I am trying to sum query whole table using Django Query. I have an also Postgresql database working with my django.

My Table workoutsummaryview: (actually its VIEW statements):

| user_id | workout | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bench | 281.31 |
| 1 | Flat | 137.06 |
| 1 | Bench | 1497.91 |
| 1 | Bench | 64.50 |
| 1 | SQ | 555.65 |
| 1 | Wrench | 2803.39 |
| 1 | Flat | 2115.73 |
| 1 | Bench | 10578.63 |
| 1 | Flat | 146.52 |
| 1 | Flat | 1770.65 |
| 1 | Wrench | 22.61 |

My views.py

```
def workoutsummary (request):
    dailyworkout = Dailyw.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    workout = Workout.objects.filter(user=request.user, datecompleted__isnull=True)
    dailyr = Dailyw.objects.aggregate(Sum('results')).values()
```

My models.py

```
class Daily(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    results = models.BigIntegerField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "workoutsummaryview"
```

According the django [aggregation reference page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) I did try on template like :

```
 {{ results }}
```

and

```
{{ dailyr.results__sum }}
```

But nothing happens.  I also tried with if and for tag, but that didn't work either. I think so i missed something important.   I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe workout object is empty

Comment: Did you try to debug the django code? Do you get the value there and just don't show anything in the view? or do you not even get a value workoutsummary variables?

Comment: check if **Workout.objects.filter(user=request.user, datecompleted__isnull=True)** is empty or not

Comment: are you sending `dailyr`'s value to template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments, probably aggregation results are empty. If that's a case, you can handle this situation by doing this:

```
Dailyw.objects.aggregate(Sum('results'))['results__sum'] or 0
```

, then in the template you'll see a value (zero) instead of black space.